Shape mismatch error in a multi-input model with Keras API
My intention is to have a classification model where different types of input could have individual hidden layers before being concatenated downstream. I get the error (below) stating that my input shapes are different from expected when I add an extra hidden layers with number of nodes larger than the input dimension of the corresponding input branch:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_21" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 3), found shape=(None, 2).
My understanding is that after I add an extra layer with more nodes the dimension of the input dimensions for that branch should not change (?). The extra layer for each branch is commented in the code snippet I provided; in this case, the model runs/trains as expected. Please, point me to what I am missing including. My semi-pseudo-code:
# dim_meta & dim_vec - are 1D dimensions of data 
def create_multiinput_model():
    dr = 0.2
    data_inputs = []

    # branch meta
    input_m = keras.layers.Input(shape=(dim_meta,))
    input_m = keras.layers.Dense(int(dim_meta*1.5), activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3))(input_m)
    input_m = keras.layers.Dropout(dr)(input_m)
    # n_nodes = int(dim_meta*1.5)
    # input_m = keras.layers.Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=dim_meta, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3))(input_m)
    # input_m = keras.layers.Dropout(dr)(input_m)
    data_inputs.append( input_m )

    # data branches
    for i in range(3):
        input_d = keras.layers.Input(shape=(dim_vec,))
        input_d = keras.layers.Dense(dim_vec, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3))(input_d)
        input_d = keras.layers.Dropout(dr)(input_d)
        # n_nodes = int(dim_vec*1.5)
        # input_d = keras.layers.Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3))(input_d)
        # input_d = keras.layers.Dropout(dr)(input_d)
        data_inputs.append( input_d )

    merged = keras.layers.Concatenate()(data_inputs)
    merged = keras.layers.Dense(int(dim*1.5), activation='relu', kernel_constraint=MaxNorm(3))(merged)
    merged = keras.layers.Dropout(dr)(merged)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(merged)

    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=data_inputs, outputs=output)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    return model

train_data = [x_train_m, x_train_d1, x_train_d2, x_train_d3,]
test_data = [x_test_m, x_test_d1, x_test_d2, x_test_d3,]

bs = 256
model = create_multiinput_model()
model.fit(x=train_data, y=y_train, validation_data=(test_data, y_test), epochs=300, batch_size=bs, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

